# cookie does not adding

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I'm adding cookie on the server:

```
private void AddCookie(int id)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("wmpayment");
    cookie.Value = id.ToString();
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
    this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

but when I am read cookie from Request - cookie.Expire equals date 01.01.0001

```
public static int WMPendingOrder
{
    get
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["wmpayment"];
        int id = 0;
        DateTime exp;

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(cookie.Expires.ToString(), out exp);
            if (DateTime.Now < exp)
                int.TryParse(cookie.Value, out id);
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

log: *COOKIE.Name: wmpayment COOKIE.Value: 0 COOKIE.Expire: 01.01.0001 0:00:00*
I am not understand what the problem.

Comment: there is something wrong with this line.."and than when I read - expires = 01.01.0001:".. please change it.. it difficult to understand what you want..

Comment: I have found this tutorial helpfull you can consider this as alternative: http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2010/10/19/howto-create-and-remove-cookies-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: I solved this problem as follows. Just to simply reset the value of the cookie - set orderId to '0'. But very interesting why browser do not remove cookie after removing it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are basically two pieces of information you need to persist. The id and an expiry date. How about storing the expiry date in a separate cookie:

```
private void AddCookie(int id) 
{ 
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("wmpayment"); 
    cookie.Value = id.ToString(); 
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2); 
    this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); 

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("wmpaymentexpire"); 
    cookie.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString(); 
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2); 
    this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); 
}
```

So to check the expires date for cookie `wmpayment` you read the value of cookie `wmpaymentexpire`.

Comment: I do not think that this is a good variant. I want to understand the problem.

Comment: Fair enough if you don't like my suggestion. But as Jonathan Rupp wrote in his answer, the client is NOT sending the expiry date of it's cookie back to the server. So you can set the expiry date of the cookie on the server and send that to the client. But the client does not send it back, so you cannot read it on the server. Only the name and the value of the cookie is sent from the cleint to the server.

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't known about it. well, can you tell me why after deleting the cookies on the server it exists on the client?

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx) for details about how to cause a client to remove a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to creating a cookie:

```
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;

            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, UsrNm, DateTime.Now,
      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "Issue Ticket");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);

            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
                ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

            string strRedirect;
            strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
            if (strRedirect == null)
                strRedirect = "~/default.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
```

**Note:**add the assembly `using System.Web.Security` for `FormsAuthenticationTicket`

Answer (score 0):

When cookies are submitted back to the server, they do not contain the 'Expires' option, so `exp` isn't being populated, so it keeps it's default value, DateTIme.MinValue.  Because of that, `DateTime.Now < exp` is never true, so `int.TryParse(cookie.Value, out id)` never runs, so id keeps it's default value, `0`.

Try this instead:

```
public static int WMPendingOrder
{
    get
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["wmpayment"];
        int id = 0;

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            int.TryParse(cookie.Value, out id);
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

You don't need to check for expired cookies server-side - if they expire, the client won't send them.

Comment: I remain in the cookie order id before submitting a request for webmoney merchant. if the payment order is successful, I delete the cookie, if not, I am display anchor with the message that user have pending payment order. So I need check Expire cookie

Comment: @user571874: If the 'Expires' value is important, you need to store it as the value of a cookie (either encoded into the same cookie, or in a separate one as suggested by @user1429080).  The client doesn't send the cookie expiration information back to the server - just the name and value.